# To stay on the current page on submitting page but should display new items PHP

Tags: php

I have a page called file.php, it has a form in it, but when the page is submitted it should stay on this page itself and the form should not be shown, instead it should display a message "Welcome".

The sample code is

```
    <form name="fn" method="post" action="postib.php">
   <table align="center" border="1" >

 <TR><TD>Job Title</TD><TD><input type="text" name="jobtitle"/></TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>Job Description</TD><TD><input type="textarea" name="jobdescription"/></TD></TR>
         <TR><TD>Location</TD><TD><select name="locid" id="locid" size="1"     style="width:190px;" onchange="showsub();"><option value="1" title="Any Location">Any    Location</option>
         <input type="submit">
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the actual code you have. Even better: post a short, self-contained, runnable example that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: when submitting i need to mail the posted values and also display "Welcome" on this page itself.

Comment: You need to post the *actual code you have*. What you've put in the question is not PHP, nor even valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden iframe:

```
<iframe id="my_hidden_iframe" style="display:none;></iframe>
```

Then set the target of your form to this iframe and set an onSubmit for the form:

```
<form id="my_form" target="my_hidden_iframe" onSubmit="submit_form_function();">
```

Create a welcome message div that is hidden by default:

```
<div id="my_welcome_message" style="display: none;">Welcome...</div>
```

Then have the submit_form_function() hide the form and add a welcome message:

```
function submit_form_function() {
    $('#my_form').hide();
    $('#my_welcome_message').show();
}
```

The above code uses JQuery, you can also do this without a JS library:

```
function submit_form_function() {
    document.getElementById('my_form').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('my_welcome_message').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: mail function also i can write like this ?

Comment: Your PHP mail function should be in the file that the form's action is set to. So the form variables will be posted to that file in the hidden iframe.

Comment: but with ajax i want to hide the already form and display a new Message

Comment: Doable with javascript. (Asynchronous **Javascript** and XML) ;)